# PyMongo insert_one exception/error handling

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to make sure I have set up error handling. I am not sure if I am using try, except, and return correctly.

The desired output is True or False
True if the document is inserted successfully, False if not. Have I done it correctly? My concern that is that it will always return true? Not exactly sure how try/except works.Thank you.

```
import json
import pymongo
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import errors

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['city']
collection = db['inspections']

def insert_document(documentToInsert):
    try:
      collection.insert_one(documentToInsert)
      return True
    except WriteConcernError as wce:
      print(wce)
      return False
    except WriteError as we:
      print(we)
      return False


def main():
    document = { 
      "id" : "11111-2019-ENFO",
      "certificate_number" : 9278806,
      "business_name" : "TAXOLOGY",
      "date" : "Feb 20 2015",
      "result" : "No Violation Issued",
      "sector" : "Accounting - 111",
      "address" :
      {
        "city" : "MISSION HILLS",
        "zip" : 91401,
        "street" : "Sepulveda",
        "number" : 1809
      }
    }

    print(insert_document(document))

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any [write_concern](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html) being passed-in as an option to your writes, I would assume you might not see `WriteConcernError`. Check this : [pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern/) for examples on how to set `WriteConcern` . Also those error checks are only needed if you wanted to execute certain functionality if a certain type of an error occurred, As all you need is to return `True` / `False`, then you can remove all those error checks :

**Code :**

```
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['city']
collection = db['inspections']


def insert_document(documentToInsert):
    try:
        collection.insert_one(documentToInsert)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred ::", e)
        return False


def main():
    document = {
        "id": "11111-2019-ENFO",
        "certificate_number": 9278806,
        "business_name": "TAXOLOGY",
        "date": "Feb 20 2015",
        "result": "No Violation Issued",
        "sector": "Accounting - 111",
        "address":
        {
            "city": "MISSION HILLS",
            "zip": 91401,
            "street": "Sepulveda",
            "number": 1809
        }
    }

    print(insert_document(document))


main()
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but what is ::, is that some formatting or you are just printing those characters. But my other question is, if collection.insert_one has an error, does it still return True or does it skip that?

Comment: @Etra : `::` It's just like we're printing it to give some space between text & actual exception when printed together, if `collection.insert_one` has an error it should be handled at `except` with function returning `False` .. You can test it by passing `_id: 123` in your document & try inserting same document twice - as in mongo `_id` is unique by default it would throw an error & in expect error will be printed & then by function returns `False`..

Comment: That really clears it up, I was not sure how to actually get an error to test it, but I forgot about _id completely. I understand try/else now and error catching much better. Thanks again.